# Print layout change

Tags: libreoffice

#### Translation to English:

My job mainly relies on LibreOffice 5 Calc and Writer.

So far the problem I faced was the ever-changing print layouts, for example, today I create a document and then edit to customize the look in the paper later during printing. After the editing process is complete, I do print the document and then I save my file.

The next day I opened the file to print again. When I print preview to change the layout turned out that I was forced to re-edit the file.

My question is, how do I make a print layout that has been edited from a document / file is not changed again when we need the document at a later time.

---

#### Original question in Indonesian language

Pekerjaan saya mengandalkan libroffice 5 terutama libreoffice calc dan writer.
sejauh ini permasalahan yang saya hadapi adalah print layout yang selalu berubah, misalnya hari ini saya membuat dokumen kemudian melakukan edit untuk menyesuaikan tampilan di kertasnya nanti saat melakukan pencetakan. Setelah proses edit selesai, saya lakukan pencetakan dokumen tersebut lalu saya simpan filenya.Esoknya saya membuka file tersebut untuk melakukan pencetakan kembali. Saat saya print preview ternyata layoutnya berubah sehingga saya terpaksa mengedit kembali file tersebut.
Pertanyaan saya, bagaimana caranya agar layout print yang sudah di edit dari suatu dokumen /file tersebut tidak berubah lagi saat kita memerlukan dokumen tersebut di lain waktu. Terima kasih atas jawabannya.

Comment: Which speficic layout modifcations were missing exactly the next day? Do you use custom styles (paragraph, page, character) and/or document templates? Or did you assign style modifications to the document parts manually (e.g, instead of creating a paragraph style for paragraphs in italic and assign that style to a paragraph, manually assign "italics" to a paragraph by selecting it and using the toolbar or shortcut)?